# Can't check if model conform to protocol Swift

Tags: swift

I Have protocol:

```
protocol SelectingRowProtocol : class {

    func selectItemAtIndexPath(row: Int)
}
```

And model:

```
class HRVacanciesViewModel :  BaseModel, CDTableAdapterViewModel, SelectingRowProtocol {


weak var selectingRowDelegate : SelectingRowProtocol?

/* Selecting */

func selectItemAtIndexPath(row: Int) {
  print("selected")
}
```

But when i try to check, if model conform to protocol, it evaluate to false:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if let model = self.viewModel as? SelectingRowProtocol {
        //currentVC responds to the MyCustomProtocol protocol =]
    }
}
```

Why is that happening?

Comment: Have you assigned selectingRowDelegate to self ?

Comment: If you print `self.viewModel` before the test, what does it show you?

Comment: `SelectingRowProtocol.Type`

Comment: @Jack not yet, but i implement protocol.

Comment: @PhillipMills it's oly show <AppName>.HRVacanciesViewModel

Comment: @Desdenova thanks but it does not help.

Comment: Does `viewModel` variable's class conforms to `SelectingRowProtocol`?

Comment: @AhmadF yes, its HRVacanciesViewModel, i posted code above.

Comment: Well, it seems kind of weird to me; This code: `protocol SelectingRowProtocol : class {
    
    func selectItemAtIndexPath(row: Int)
}

class Model: SelectingRowProtocol {
    func selectItemAtIndexPath(row: Int) {
        print("selected")
    }
}

let myModel: Model? = Model()

if let unwrappedModel = myModel as? SelectingRowProtocol {
    print("works!")
}` should log "works!" and I think that you are having the same case...

Comment: @AhmadF but in case i post code it does not work (

Comment: Why do you perform the check at **runtime**? If you call `selectItemAtIndexPath` in `didSelectRowAt`  you will get an error at **compile time** if the calling class does not conform to the protocol

Comment: @vadian because i have independent class for managing table data source and delegate that know nothing about view controller

Comment: @vadian i ended up with         (self.viewModel as! SelectingRowProtocol).selectItemAtIndexPath(row: indexPath.row)
, if you have better solution i would be glad to hear it

Answer (score 1):

> You can try making the protocol method as optional in order to avoid
>   forced wrapping

```
@objc protocol SelectingRowProtocol : class {
  optional func selectItemAtIndexPath(row: Int)
}
```

> And you can check if your viewmodel conforms to protocol like this:-

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  if self.viewModel is SelectingRowProtocol { //Should returns true
    //currentVC responds to the MyCustomProtocol protocol =]
//now call like this
(self.viewModel as? SelectingRowProtocol)?.selectItemAtIndexPath?(row: indexPath.row)
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks but why you add Obj-C And optional? Why my code not work?

Comment: For making the method optional but it is not mandatory you can use if you required your protocol method to be optional